# Записать значение в поле из модели

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-record

В таблице `Users` имеется поле `unsubscription_token`
После сохранения формы регистрации пользователя я хочу записать в это поле случайную строку и делаю из модели `user` вот что:

```
  before_save :unsubscription_token

  def unsubscription_token
    unsubscription_token = SecureRandom.hex
  end
```

Но это не срабатывает, как быть?

Comment: В смысле, не срабатывает? unsubscription_token остаётся пустым? А что в логах сервера при регистрации, особенно касаемо этого поля?

Comment: этого поля нет в передаваемых параметрах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
before_save :set_token

def set_token
  self.unsubscription_token = SecureRandom.hex
  # self.unsubscription_token = SecureRandom.hex if self.token.blank?
end
```